# Managing the function main

Tags: java, button, jlist, program-entry-point

I created a class `A` that reads a text file and alters some lines within the text, and the code is written in `main()` of this class. I also created another class `B` that has a `Frame`, the `Frame` contains a list of text files of a directory and a button. What I don't know how to do is this: When I click on the selected item on the list and click the button, the function main is called and the selected item is being read by `main()`.

Any suggestion is welcomed and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want the `main` to be called in that case? Just leave it for its purpose, which is to be the program's entry point. Have another function (probably non-static) for your processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have code in the static main method, you have a non-object oriented code block, one that won't easily be used by other object oriented-compliant portions of your program. The best solution here is to get all code but the minimal out of main and create a true OOP-compliant class, one that can be more easily used by your other classes.

Your other issue is the mixing of your text-processing code with your GUI code, and this may require further fixing, especially if the text-processing code takes a while to complete or is a CPU hog. If so, you'll need to take care to do the text-processing in a thread that is background to the GUI thread, and again, this is much more easily performed if the text-processing code is in a well-behaved OOP class.

Answer (score 3):

The main method is just like any other method, you call it the same way.

```
class A {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String filename = args[0];
    }
}

class B {
    public void onFilename(String filename) {
        A.main(filename);
    }
}
```

You might want to use a background thread instead of locking up the GUI while it is processing. ;)